# Listar arquivos de um pasta em Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como uso a biblioteca [`os`](http://turing.com.br/pydoc/2.7/tutorial/stdlib.html) para listar arquivos de um determinado diretório.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes sobre as dificuldades encontradas, e suas dúvidas/problemas sobre a realização de uma tarefa em específico.

Answer (score 14):

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). Você passa um caminho (relativo ou absoluto) e ele te dá os nomes de todos os arquivos, pastas e links contidos no mesmo. Aí você pode filtrar por arquivo, se quiser (usando [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)), ou por outros critérios:

```
import os

caminhos = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]
jpgs = [arq for arq in arquivos if arq.lower().endswith(".jpg")]
```

Nota: se você estiver usando Python 2, e passar uma string comum (e não um `unicode`), os resultados virão como strings comuns, o que pode causar problemas caso haja arquivos com acentos no nome. Recomenda-se portanto usar Unicode em todas as operações, convertendo explicitamente para `unicode` caso tenha dúvida quanto ao tipo.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), ele retorna uma tupla com o path, diretorio, arquivo, como você está interessado somente no arquivo, pode ignorar as duas primeiras partes, fazendo:

```
for _, _, arquivo in os.walk('/home/user'):
    print(arquivo)
```

Comment: Caraca, esse comando é bom demais! Resolveu meu problema de forma ímpar

Answer (score 5):

Olá.
O pacote os, oferece uma gama de possibilidades.

**path recursivo + arquivo**

```
import os

def files_path04(path):
    for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
        file in files:
            print(os.path.join(p, file)))

files_path04('/tmp')
```

Um exemplo para multiplos diretórios:

```
def files_path05(*args):
    for item in args:
        for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(item)):
            for file in files:
                print(os.path.join(p, file))

files_path05('/home', '/tmp')
```

Ainda pode configurar um retorno com uma lista de string, contendo o arquivo ou uma tupla separando o path e arquivo.

```
def files_path06(*args):
    l = []
    for item in args:
        for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(item)):
            for file in files:
                l.append((p, file))
    return l

files_path06('/home', '/tmp')
```

Listagem através de lista de compreensão

```
def files_path09(path):
    '''return list of tuple(path, file)'''
    return [(p, file) for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)) for file in files]


def files_path10(path):
    '''return list of string'''
    return [os.path.join(p, file) for p, _, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)) for file in files]
```

Listagem com recurso pathlib python 3.8.x

```
def files_path11(path):
    p = pathlib.Path(path)
    return list(p.glob(**/*))
```

Answer (score 1):

Se sua pretensão for listar apenas os arquivos de um **determinado diretório** você pode:

1. Informar o caminho do diretório;
2. Solicitar a exibição dos arquivos deste diretório.

Para isso podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir
from os.path import isfile

cam = input('Digite o caminho: ')

chdir(cam)
print(getcwd())

for c in listdir():
    if isfile(c):
        print(c)
```

Agora, se você pretende exibir **todo o conteúdo** de um determinado diretório - pastas e arquivos - você pode:

1. Informar o caminho do diretório;
2. Solicitar a exibição de todo o conteúdo do respectivo diretório.

Para isso podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir

cam = input('Digite o caminho: ')

chdir(cam)
print(getcwd())

for c in listdir():
    print(c)
```