# Automatizar a leitura de vários arquivos texto num script Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho um script Python que conta o número de conexões contidas num arquivo texto e que está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
with open('1zao.txt') as f:
    linhas = f.readlines()

soma = 0
for linha in linhas:
    soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])

print("O total por segundo eh",soma)
```

Onde 1zao.txt é assim:

```
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.115
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.119
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.122
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.133
  3 10:19:00 192.168.91.137
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.149
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.180
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.49
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.73
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.76
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.90
  1 10:19:00 192.168.91.96
  1 10:19:01 192.168.91.108
  1 10:19:01 192.168.91.119
  1 10:19:01 192.168.91.124
```

Número|  horário|  IP

Os arquivos de entradas são todos da forma `1zao.txt,2zao.txt... 80zao.txt`

Gostaria de modificar o script Python acima de forma a não ter que ficar trocando o nome do arquivo texto a cada vez que eu executá-lo.

```
Gostaria que a saída fosse num arquivo, por exemplo resultado.txt:

  1->  O total por segundo no arquivo 1zao.txt é: soma

  2->  O total por segundo no arquivo 2zao.txt é: soma
```

É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar oque foi explicado nesta pergunta: [Listar arquivos de um pasta em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63097/listar-arquivos-de-um-pasta-em-python)

```
#encoding: utf-8
import os    

#lista apenas os arquivos txt da pasta
pasta = "c:\scripts"
caminhos = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]    
arquivos_txt = [arq for arq in arquivos if arq.lower().endswith(".txt")]

#cria uma lista para armazenar as saídas
saida = []    

#percorre os arquivos
for arq in arquivos_txt:    
  #abre o arquivo 
  with open(arq) as f:
      linhas = f.readlines()

  #soma os valores
  soma = 0
  for linha in linhas:
     soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])

  #guarda na lista de saida  
  saida.append("O total por segundo no arquivo {} é: {} \n".format(arquivos_txt,soma))

#grava a lista em um novo arquivo
arq_saida = open('/arquivo_saida.txt', 'w')
arq_saida.writelines(saida)
arq_saida.close()
```

Comment: Lindo código. Vou testar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: é possível  a saída num arquivo, por exemplo resultado.txt:
    
      1->  O total por segundo no arquivo 1zao.txt é: soma
    
      2->  O total por segundo no arquivo 2zao.txt é: soma

Comment: Rodei o script com o caminho do arquivo atualizado mas não fez nada! Aqui está o código: https://pastebin.com/Q9Rxs35F

Comment: Alterei para ele gravar em um arquivo e coloquei para ele imprimir quantos arquivos ele listou, pode rodar e me dizer se ele retorna algum arquivo

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Testarei agora e darei o retorno!

Comment: rodou mas deu "0 arquivos listados" e o arquivo de saida vazio!

Comment: Tinha um problema no seguinte trecho, `caminhos = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]`, fiz a correção

Comment: testarei de novo! Obrigado

Comment: O erro agora foi:       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Radhe/LabAbril2017Capturas/slices_calculos/10Abril/timeSlices_1min/slowloris/Slices_1min/contar_Otimizado2.py", line 16, in <module>
    linhas = f.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: O erro foi http://imgur.com/a/LCncf

Comment: O erro parece estar acontecendo por causa do Unicode de um arquivo, você está usando aquele exemplo que você passou? ou existem mais arquivos? Se sim você consegue ver em qual arquivo ele disparou o erro?

Comment: Na pasta existem arquivos PCAP também. Tem como dizer ao script pra ver apenas os arquivos da forma xzao.txt?

Comment: Editado para retornar apenas arquivos .txt

Comment: NameError: name 'arq' is not defined

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61938/discussion-between-jose-henrique-luckmann-and-ed-s).