# Listar arquivos de uma pasta utilizando os.listdir

Tags: python

Quero listar os arquivos de uma pasta utilizando o `os.listdir` no Python mas não retorna nada. O código que fiz:

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # (1) obter nomes de arquivos de uma pasta
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\FotosUdacity\prank")
    rename_files()
```

Comment: [Há uma ajuda completa com diversos exemplos neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63097/listar-arquivos-de-um-pasta-em-python/298310#298310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso te ajuda?

```
from os import listdir

def listar_arquivos(caminho=None):
    lista_arqs = [arq for arq in listdir(caminho)]
    return lista_arqs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arquivos = listar_arquivos(caminho="/seu/caminho/")
    print(arquivos)
```

Comment: Tive dúvida sobre como fazer tal listagem e sua resposta me auxilio bastante. Obrigado Bruno!